# In what case can this if-statement throw an exception?

Tags: c++, if-statement, stdstring, outofrangeexception

Apparently, when my code reaches this `if` statement, a `string subscript out of range` exception occurs.

```
// a is int
// str is std::string

while ( true )
{    
// other stuff
if( a == str.size() ) // this line throws an exception
    break;
}
```

In what case can such a simple if-statement throw an exception? I just don't see it. Shouldn't it simply return `0` if for some reason the comparison fails?

EDIT:
This is the full function in which it occurs. It basically reads through a file and takes in the value of some tokens of its.
And if it is of some relevancy, I'm using *Visual Studio 2010 Express* and the error says "Debug Assertion Failed".

```
void Function(string &str, int start)
{
    int outline;

    // Read all attributes
    int pos, pos2 = start;
    while( true )
    {       
        pos = SkipWhiteSpace(str, pos2);
        pos2 = FindEndOfToken(str, pos);

        string token = str.substr(pos, pos2-pos);

        pos = SkipWhiteSpace(str, pos2);
        if( pos == str.size() || str[pos] != '=' ) break;

        pos = SkipWhiteSpace(str, pos+1);
        pos2 = FindEndOfToken(str, pos);
        file<<"...part 3";

        string value = str.substr(pos, pos2-pos);

        if( token == "outline" )
            outline = (short)strtol(value.c_str(), 0, 10);

        if( pos == str.size() ) // <--- error here (at least, it seems so)
            break;      
    }

    SetOutline(outline);
}
```

And the `SkipWhiteSpace()` and `FindEndOfToken()` functions are these two.

```
int SkipWhiteSpace(string &str, int start)
{
    UINT n = start;
    while( n < str.size() )
    {
        char ch = str[n];
        if( ch != ' ' && 
            ch != '\t' && 
            ch != '\r' && 
            ch != '\n' )
            break;

        ++n;
    }

    return n;
}

int FindEndOfToken(string &str, int start)
{
    UINT n = start;
    if( str[n] == '"' )
    {
        n++;
        while( n < str.size() )
        {
            char ch = str[n];
            if( ch == '"' )
            {
                // Include the last quote char in the token
                ++n;
                break;
            }
            ++n;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while( n < str.size() )
        {
            char ch = str[n];
            if( ch == ' ' ||
                ch == '\t' ||
                ch == '\r' ||
                ch == '\n' ||
                ch == '=' )
                break;

            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Comment: This line would throw an exception if the code ahead of it exhibited undefined behavior, and illegally modified the content of `str`'s internals.

Comment: If anything `// other stuff` (whatever it really is) is a suspect.

Comment: Stack overflow due to compare signed/unsigned (I assume a becomes negative)

Comment: Good point, I know GCC warns for signed/unsigned comparisons.

Comment: @chris I thought this was a fair enough SSCCE; I can't see how to reproduce this otherwise, though. EDIT: I'm gonna add the full code if it helps;

Comment: Is the string modified in "other stuff"? What's the value of "a"? You need to give us a bit more to work off here.

Comment: Well, now that the comparison issue was brought up, it could be, but there's nothing we can really test to recreate the problem and play around to fix it.

Comment: I added the full function in which it occurs

Comment: Are you 100% sure it says "string _submission_ out of range"? Isn't it rather "string _subscript_ out of range"?

Comment: Err... it actually is _subscript_. I hope I din't facepalm'd too bad...

Comment: Did you try clicking the `Retry` button in the "Debug Assertion Failed!" pop-up window then explore back the call stack in the debugger?

Comment: It triggers a breakpoint and brings me over `if(::_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ASSERT, file, line, NULL, message)==1)
        {
            ::_CrtDbgBreak();
        }`, but I don't know how to read the debug after that

Comment: Sorry, we can't debug your (incomplete) code for you (yes, incomplete: where's the `main`?). You need to use your IDE with its debugger and Call Stack window ([this](http://loulou.developpez.com/tutoriels/cpp/debogueur-visual-studio/images/vectormain.png)).

Comment: That's exactly why I asked in which case such an error could occur. I could never ask someone else to fully debug my code.

Comment: @Banderi Dammit, use some unsigned type when comparing to container.size().

Comment: ,,. that code is weird enough.

Comment: @DieterLücking I quickly tried to forcefully keep all the types to unsigned, it either didn't work or the problem is not that one. However I'm 99% sure that the exception/error/whatever occurs in that very line of code.. Anyway, I didn't write that code. I'm just using it, and the author said it never had such a problem before and it still works for him.

Comment: @DieterLücking Well, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @Banderi This is a really bad bet: Find a -1 passed to your functions.

Comment: Searched for a good hour, still nothing like that. Instead, I found that before reaching the end of the main token (the if-statement) there was another part it was parsing, and the actual error is in the `FindEndOfToken()` function. I'm gonna look inside it... I apologize for making you guys waste time after a ghost, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line can never throw an exception. Are you sure what you get is a real C++ exception and not a crash?

Comment: Well, the visual error message says "exception" ans "string submission out of range", so I thought it was a simple exception..
The error is the "Debug Assertion Failed!" message and points to line 1441 of file "xstring", saying that it is an exception. After that, it crashes.

Comment: Theoretically, it could throw some kind of integer overflow/out of range exception, if the coercion of `a` (assuming it is really an `int` aka `std::int32_t`) and `std::size_t` did not work and if the underlying run-time supports and observes that... Hm, a bit of too many "ifs"

Comment: Pardon. It's _subscript_, not _submission_.

Comment: This line could throw an exception if there was undefined behavior in the program.  You can never say never in C++, because of undefined behavior.

Comment: And of course, "Debug Assertion Failed" is not what we would usually consider an exception.  It generally means that his instance of the string is corrupt somehow.

Comment: My bad again, it appears it is not that one line that causes the error. I'm gonna look for it, but I think this question can be considered closed.